# I'm getting different website Sourcecode if i use a program or a browser

Tags: java, html, http, cookies, web

With this Code I am trying to get the complete sourcecode:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class URLConnectionReader extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    TextArea ta;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                System.out.println("hallo");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        Button btn = new Button();
        System.out.println("1");
        btn.setText("Go!");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("2");
            try {
                show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Hello World!");

        }
    });

    ta = new TextArea();
    ta.setFocusTraversable(false);
    ta.setEditable(false);

    HBox comps = new HBox();
    comps.getChildren().add(btn);
    comps.getChildren().add(ta);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(comps);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 950));
    primaryStage.show();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void show() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("3");
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://www.backpack.tf/classifieds?quality=6&tradable=1&craftable=1&australium=-1&quality=5");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("4");

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        ta.appendText(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

}

That shows the sourcecode of the website http://www.backpack.tf/classifieds?quality=6&tradable=1&craftable=1&australium=-1&quality=5.
The program shows a output, but if I open the same page with firefox and look at the website sourcecode there, its longer. How can I make my programm put out the whole code? Do I have to use Coocies or make the User Agent bigger?

Comment: Send the exact same headers your browser does, and you should get same response.

Comment: I would suggest to use a tool like Fiddler to catch your browser's session, then try to set exactly the same headers as your browser do. One by one.

Comment: Ok, did that. Now i dont even get HTML code, but sth. like that: `?:ST3?úùú™C1‡HËvD+p²TÐÖÎc‚mU?/`©$Ð?ÑÏ”U¨„¦A
|@&'X·Î¡“¸0ýÒyôB½(”?÷‡¢/]c|? WØ›;«öJ‚V·§Ðé¬3k²I\+»È<hNŒª¤³$«<”œ°R,£}?žçJº˜‹vž“×Ã÷ÃË9Tn‚¨k­¤@å,½U¦‘?h8ÅÄ
ß°a~ž˜O7¹Q6—!?]•p­!T` with this headers: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 ; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate ; Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 ; User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0 ; DNT: 1 ; Connection: keep-alive ; Host: backpack.tf . so, its eaven worse. Can I do anything else?